# In Plone is it possible to remove certain stripped and nasty tags for manager role only?

Tags: security, plone

I'd like to side-step some of the security filtering done by Plone but only for people with manager or site admin roles. I want regular members to be able to add content but that content should still be filtered. Specifically at this moment I'm looking at allowing iFrames for manager role but this question is also more generic. The access to Plone that I'm referring to is a person editing a site page through Plone's standard editing system, TinyMCE.

Comment: You meant: from the WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the TinyMCE code you'll see that it load some configuration from the server. through the `safe_html` tranform inside the `portal_transforms` tool (
see https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/11b957652846679cf7f441cc956730bd6fc92f87/Products/TinyMCE/utility.py#L499).

You can simply patch the `getValidElements` method above (adding here some user permission checking before removing/adding stripped tags) but it's not enough: this will simply change TinyMCE behavior (client side) but an evil user can access your site with TinyMCE disabled (really simple to do, just disable JavaScript in the browser), then upload a custom HTML without those filters.

So: the best thing to do is to customize the `safe_html` transform with the same permission checking. The simple way to add new stuff here withouy monkey-patching is to register a new `plone.outputfilters` adapter as described here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.outputfilters#adding-a-custom-filter

Comment: Thanks for teaching. I expect the link in para3 to take me to where I have to go; gives me peace of mind!

Answer (score 0):

Simply patching safe_html will not work for several reasons:

1. html is not only filtered on save but also on display. That means that admins would see your iframe but normal users would not.
2. The filter is only executed once at the first display and then cached for one hour. Adding code that distinguishes between roles would have no effect on the second visitor.